# Microsoft Visual C++ syntax "^"

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

Can't find an answer to this for the life of me...

In the following line of code what does the ^ do?

```
RegistryKey^ rk;
```

I only ever see this in Windows code samples. How has Microsoft corrupted my binary operator?

Comment: Could you provide an example of where you have seen this used in samples?

Comment: It is used in the C++/CLI and C++/CX language extensions, they support interop with non-C++ types.  Respectively for .NET types and WinRT types.  .NET here.  The concept is pretty powerful, you can directly call native C++ code from Javascript for example, a feat that C++ compilers can't manage themselves ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is from C++/CLI, which a C++/C# hybrid language, that runs on the same CLR that C# and VB do.

`T^` is a managed pointer, pointing at objects allocated with `gcnew`.

`T^%` is a managed reference. I've never actually used these, and know nothing of them.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI

Answer (score 0):

That's the C++/CLI (managed C++) *handle declarator* ("hat") symbol.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk97tc08.aspx